# Where do hits on "/ga/abpages/...-original.html" come from?

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently developing a website as a side-project. There's really nothing on it, and for the past few months the site has been online I've been getting no traffic except for that which I generate myself.

However, a week ago I got exactly 200 unique hits on the following url:

```
/ga/abpages/2013-08-30T02:52:53.776Z-original.html
```

Looking around, I came across [this discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/PopRDe7ATr8) (and only that discussion). The given answer, that "someone may have borrowed some of your site code" seems highly unlikely, given that all three reports match the `/ga/abpages/...-original.html` pattern, and two of them confirmed that they saw exactly 200 hits.

Additionally, the `/ga/` path makes me think the path is directly related to Googles' own `ga.js`.

Here is all the meta-data I can associate with the hits; all other demographics are not set.

- Page Title: `original page`
- Traffic: `Direct`
- Language: `en-us`
- Browser: `Chrome`
- Resolution: `1280x1024`
- OS: `Linux`

None of the hits have any navigation data associate with them—they land, then bounce.

**What are these phantom hits and where are they coming from?**

Comment: Are you using [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032399?hl=en) in your website?

Comment: @dan Yes, I am.